# How to set the value of a TIMESTAMP field with a unix epoch time?

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

This query in MySQL:

```
UPDATE my_table SET last_active = 100000 WHERE my_id = 1;
```

sets the last_active field, which is of type TIMESTAMP, to "0000-00-00 00:00:00", but I'd expect it to set it to 100000 seconds past 1970. How can I do that?

Comment: change your date type as "INT"

Comment: @uvais Thanks, but it has to be a TIMESTAMP because this is an existing application and I can't change the table structure.

Comment: Refer this link: http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/mysql-from-unixtime.php

Comment: CAST(DateTime AS TIMESTAMP).,, i think this may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert from epoch to date

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch timestamp, optional output format)
```

The default output is YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

For your code:

```
UPDATE my_table SET last_active = FROM_UNIXTIME(100000) WHERE my_id = 1;
```